# Alternative to deprecated chromedriverchromemapfile

Tags: java, android, ios, appium

I'm trying to pass in the Andriod/iOS version through our test case file (.csv) and have the in-house framework download the appropriate chromedriver automatically. I looked into `chromedriverchromemapfile` but it looks like that is a deprecated feature for UIAutomator2.

Currently, we have to manually download the appropriate chromedriver and add it to the `/bin/` directory.  I'm using Appium 1.13 and UIAutomator2, would like to be able to support 2/3 previous versions of each Android/iOS OS.

Automatic discovery of compatible Chromedriver
Beginning with Appium 1.8.0, Appium is able to pick the correct Chromedriver for the version of Chrome under test. While Appium only comes bundled with the Chromedriver most recently released at the time of the Appium version's release, more Chromedriver versions can be downloaded and either placed inside the Appium installation (not recommended since upgrading Appium will remove them) or in a custom location, which can be indicated to Appium with the chromedriverExecutableDir desired capability. This capability is the absolute path to the directory in which you have placed one or more Chromedriver executables.

As well, since new versions of Chromedriver may be available that were not when an Appium version was released, a custom mapping of Chromedrivers to the minimum Chrome version they support can be given to Appium through the chromedriverChromeMappingFile desired capability. This should be the absolute path to a file with the mapping in it. The contents of the file need to be parsable as a JSON object, like:

{
  "2.42": "63.0.3239",
  "2.41": "62.0.3202"
}

Link to the source: 
http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver/index.html

Expected:
Looking to have the framework automatically download the compatible chromedriver before each script execution.